# Poland Visa Type and Travel Deal

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, poland

I am from Kerala, India I am planning to travel to Poland and perhaps one of its neighbouring countries as it is economical.

I have a few questions.

1. There is an **International Tours & Travel Trade Fair** happening at the same time. I plan to visit the trade fair and have already registered for it. Do I need to mention it in the cover letter? Will it help my tourist visa application? (I don't have any official invitation)
2. I am planning this as a solo trip (or with a friend). Shall I attach the marriage certificate and birth certificate of my kid to prove the family ties?
3. Should I hire a travel agent so that my application is accepted?
4. **Travel History** : **Russia** (FIFA world cup), **UAE** (transit). Will it help?
5. What are my chances of getting the visa with **minimum ITR, Bank Statement and Balance**?

Comment: Welcome to Travel StackExchange! Your question concerning places to stay and things to do is probably too broad to be answered well on this site; it depends too much on your personal preferences. (In addition, it's a completely different question than your visa concerns.) I would recommend editing your question to remove that part, and (if you must) asking the itinerary question separately. See [the WANTA debate](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1445/the-wanta-debate-we-are-not-travel-agents) for guidance on how to rephrase the itinerary question if you do repost it.

Comment: We cannot say if you should go through an agency or not. It is not possible for us to tell you about the chances of acceptance. You should work on making a strong application and it is very important to have sufficient funds in your bank account. You may want to refer to this https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab

Comment: If you decide to let an agent prepare an application for you (which shouldn't be necessary for an uncomplicated tourism/business visit, but there might be factors you have not told us), it is **vitally important** that you read through the application they prepare and make sure _everything they claim on your behalf_ is 100% correct before you sign it. You will be held personally responsible for any untruths found; it is not a defense that it's an agent's work. In particular, don't believe an agency's word that it's okay to lie about such-and-such. It is not.

Comment: We have a number of sad stories on this site from victims of agents who submitted false material, or who failed to submit required material.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to mention it in the cover letter?

There is no harm in mentioning about the trade fair in your cover letter. You can provide the details about the fair and since you have already registered you can also show a receipt if you have gotten one.

> Should I attach my marriage certificate and birth certificate of my kid?

Attaching birth and marriage certificate would put some weight to your application. These documents show your strong ties to the home country and could work as a guarantee that you will return to India after your visit.

Comment: Thanks Bro, Pls see the updated question and your response is appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

You should explain:

- Why you want to go.
  Combining business and tourism is entirely normal, but make sure that you provide a clear premise of the trip. **For professional reasons** you want to go to the trade show, and **while you're in the area** you want to do some tourism. You wouldn't go without the trade fair.
- Who pays for your trip, respective how you pay for your trip.
  This is very important. If your employer sends you and pays for it, you have a very compelling reason to go. If you pay for it yourself, you should make clear how it fits into your business finances.
- Your financial and other situation at home, and that you have strong ties to your home.
  The visa official will ask himself or herself "is Roxon going to overstay or return home?" Family who stay behind may help, if it doesn't look as if you want to work in the Schengen area and send the money home.

If you get a Schengen visa for just one day, you could travel across an internal border, apply for ayslum, and start lengthy proceeding to determine if you can stay or get deported -- and from India, there is a minimal chance that you could stay. For that reason the visa for that **first** day is difficult to get, getting a few days more is comparatively easy if it looks as if you can afford it.